# Navigate with nuxt-link to anchor/hash on different page causing problems

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt-links in my website navigation, most of them point to hashed elements/anchors in the home page like:

```
<nuxt-link
  v-else
  class="text-link"
  :to="localePath('index') + `#${item.hash}`"
>
```

and it does its job if currently on the home page but when I navigate to a different site, eg. /about and I click on a navbar nuxt-link (so I want to navigate from /about to /#hash or /any-other-site#hash) I got a nuxt error displayed to check the console where it reads "Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null"

My router configuration in nuxt.config (without it I wouldn't be even able to scroll to an anchored element being in the same site as the element!):

```
  router: {
    scrollBehavior(to) {
      if (to.hash) {
        return window.scrollTo({ top: document.querySelector(to.hash).offsetTop + window.innerHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
      return window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
  },
```

Comment: Have you tried using the buildin routing option in nuxt to scroll to a specfic position on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the hash in your nuxt-link. Use:

```
<nuxt-link
  v-else
  class="text-link"
  :to="{ path: localePath('index'), hash:`#${item.hash}` }"
>
```